# How to get the Mime Type of a request in Grails?

Tags: grails, mime-types, grails-2.0

How to get the Mime Type of a request in Grails?

I used:

```
def f = request.getFile('image')
def mimeType = f.getContentType()
```

but this does not always returns the correct <strike>mime</strike> file type. How can I get File of file user selected for update?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? request.getHeader('Content-Type')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will return whatever content type the browser sent for that particular part of the posted `multipart/form-data`.  Whether or not this is the "correct" type is a different question...

Comment: @userWebMobile what do you mean by "correct"? If you don't want to believe what the client's browser tells you then there are various Java libraries that can try and infer a content-type from the file name and/or contents, including the built-in [Files.probeContentType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) if you're running on Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something like "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", so you might need to split by the ";" to get the correct value. Then you need to check if the value is valid, like checking the format, or checking against a list of valid codes, etc. If the value is not valid, you can return a 400 error to the user.